# How to upload image a random name?

Tags: php, image-uploading, file-rename

How do i give the image a random name instead of taking the name the image currently have when being uploaded?

```
   if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
  $errors= array();
  $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
  $file_tmp =$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
  $file_type=$_FILES['image']['type'];
  $file_name_array = explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name']);
  $file_ext=strtolower(end($file_name_array));

  $expensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png");

  if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)=== false){
     $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
  }


  if(empty($errors)==true){
     move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"uploads254/".$file_name);
  }else{
     print_r($errors);
  }strong text
```

Comment: `rename()` function could help you after moving the file into uploads folder: http://php.net/manual/bg/function.rename.php

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty ways to do it I recommend using [uniqid](http://php.net/uniqid)()

Change

```
move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"uploads254/".$file_name);
```

to

```
move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, "uploads254/" . uniqid(rand(), true) . $file_ext;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate random string using php `rand()` function and use it as a name of your image file.

```
function getRandomImageName($length = 10) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $imageName = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $imageName .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $imageName;
}



if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
  $errors= array();
  $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
  $file_tmp =$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
  $file_type=$_FILES['image']['type'];
  $file_name_array = explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name']);
  $file_ext=strtolower(end($file_name_array));
  $fileName = getRandomImageName(10);

  $expensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png");

  if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)=== false){
     $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
  }


  if(empty($errors)==true){
     move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"uploads254/".$fileName);
  }else{
     print_r($errors);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your value of the variable `$file_name` to `rand()` or any other name that you want to use.